# C vsnprintf() ignoring last argument

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to display a formatted string on a TFT display using a TI C2000 microcontroller. To implement this, I am using the following function.

```
void text_writeFormatAtPoint(fontHeader_t font, uint16_t x, uint16_t y, textAlignment_t align, char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list lst;
    char s[64];
    va_start(lst, fmt);
    vsnprintf(s, 63, fmt, lst);
    va_end(lst);
    text_writeTextAtPoint(font, s, x, y, align);
}
```

I call the function with the following line.

```
text_writeFormatAtPoint(f_12x16, 0, clock->face.y+30, CENTER, "%2d:%02d:%02d", hours, mins, secs);
```

On a different microcontroller, this works exactly as expected. However, on this one, only the hours and minutes are put into the string, while the seconds place remains at `00`. Through debugging I have made sure that the `secs` variable holds the correct value, and that `s` is incorrect, not the display code. Is there some feature of `vsnprintf()` I am overlooking, or could it possibly be a bug with TI's implementation of the function?

If I do the following

```
text_writeFormatAtPoint(f_12x16, 0, clock->face.y+30, CENTER, "%2d:%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, mins, secs, secs);
```

The rightmost place updates, but not the normal one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that `secs` was declared as `uint32_t` while `hours` and `mins` were `uint16_t`, so the format specifier had to be `%02ld` instead. (I'm surprised this had such a significant impact)

Answer (score 2):

You've identified the problem (wrong types), and suggested changing the seconds to `%02ld` because `secs` is `uint32_t`.  Technically this is still wrong, since `%02ld` expects `long int`.  For one thing, this is signed instead of unsigned, and not all systems necessarily encode a small unsigned integer the same way as a signed one.  For another, it will break again when you go to another system where `long int` is something other than 32 bits.

I think a better fix is to cast:

```
text_writeFormatAtPoint(f_12x16, 0, clock->face.y+30, CENTER, "%2d:%02d:%02d", (int)hours, (int)mins, (int)secs);
```